# How to combine an list of strings into a string without a separator

Tags: unity

I have a List of Strings, and I want to combine it into a single string.

So for example, if my List looks like this:

```
0: "s"
1: "t"
2: "r"
```

I would like to combine this List of Strings into the single string: "str".

I couldn't find a way to do this in Unity Visual Scripting without using a separator string.  So I tried using String Join with a " " separator, and then using String Replace to replace the " " with an empty string.  That worked well, until I encountered this bug (the "e" string becomes an "st").

[image]

I suspect the error is tied somehow to the immutable nature of strings, combined with some sort of human error on my part.

Is there a simpler way to combine a List of Strings into a single String, without using a separator string?

Comment: Ohh.... there's a String Concat Values node that does exactly this!

Comment: Want to post that as an Answer below?

Comment: It didn't work, there's something about string immutability that I don't understand.  I'll try to narrow it down and then edit the question!

Comment: When you say "didn't work", what was your input, what was the output, and how did the output differ from what you expected?

Comment: Can you try using underscore instead of a space for a separator, and replacing that with empty string?